# listing folder ending with whitespace

Tags: directory, ls

I would like to list this folder `mnt/test`.
(test with a whitespace at the end)
I tried the following different syntaxes:

```
ls mnt/test 
ls "mnt/test "
ls mnt/test\ 
ls "mnt/test\ "
```

All of these attempts failed.

Is there any solution besides renaming the folder?

Comment: Can't you just use tab completion (i.e. type `ls mnt/test` and then press TAB) to fill in the rest of the name? What kind of whitespace is it anyway, apparently it doesn't seem to be a simple space...

Comment: The output of `ls -db mnt/*` might be helpful

Comment: Normally "mnt/test " should work. To make sure that you don't have other invisible characters in your folder name, do `ls -d mnt/test* | od -xc`.

Answer (score 0):

On my PC `ls mnt/test\` and `ls mnt/test\ /` (no quotes) work well.

```
:~$ mkdir -p "mnt/test "
:~$ cd mnt/test\ /
:~/mnt/test $ touch 1 2 3 4 5
:~/mnt/test $ cd
:~$ ls mnt/test\ 
1  2  3  4  5
:~$ ls mnt/test\ /
1  2  3  4  5
```